# How to fail declarative Jenkins pipeline if maven tests fail?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am running a declarative pipeline like this -

```
stage ('Integration Tests') {
    steps {
      bat "mvn clean verify"
    }
}
```

How can I fail this pipeline if integration tests fail? I have tried wrapping the step inside a `script` with `try-catch` block but that did not help. I am using JBehave Maven plugin to trigger integration tests.

Comment: can you share you POM file?

Comment: Sharing the POM would not be possible anything in particular that I can post?

Comment: can you share the the surefire plugin section

Comment: I don't have that in pom, it's being run by JBehave framework.

Comment: so how you are running your tests? can you share what plugin you are using in the POM to run the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBehave Maven plugin has a flag `ignoreFailureInStories` that needed to be set as true in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so based on my understanding you should add:
**-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false** to the **MAVEN_OPTS** if you click on Advanced button in the Build section of your Jenkins Job.

See  [Maven Surefire Plugin - surefire:test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) options for reference.

This is due to jenkins specifies this value to true per default. Have a look at [issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655)

Comment: Actually you pointed me to the right direction :) the [JBehave Maven plugin](https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/maven-goals.html) has a flag `ignoreFailureInStories` that needed to be set as `true` in my case. It's solved now. Thanks!